# Can we implement countdown feature for the slack message?

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

Is there a way to implement the countdown feature for the slack message using Slack API?

The message should only be valid for specified amount of time and then it should disappear or stop user interaction with it.

Comment: please add a sample code into you question.

Comment: It's just a question rather than coding error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes technically this is possible. To display the countdown you need to use two methods, that is [`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) and [`chat.update`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.update). `chat.postMessage` is for posting the initial message that contains the full counter say 5 minutes. After the initial message is posted you will need to run a loop in you code that updates the initial message with the depreciating value (4 minutes, 3 minutes and so on) using the `chat.update` method. After the countdown ends you can now delete or update the blocks to remove the interactions (buttons and so on). I hope that provides some insight.

Comment: Yes, that is thoughtful and I believe this is the only option offered by slack API to implement something like count-down, unless I think of using third party app to manage the counter on front-end.